# How can I read UTXO's for specific accounts?

Tags: transactions, json-rpc

With `bitcoin`, I'd use the JSON-RPC and keep track of transactions in blocks and have to build the UTXO database myself. Is it the same with ethereum?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no such thing as UTXOs with Ethereum, it's account based instead. You can query a nodes JSON-RPC to get balances, code, storage, etc. There are also many libraries (including Web3.js) to make this much easier.

Comment: I can query ANY account balance directly, regardless of whether or not I have the private keys?

Comment: Correct. You do not need an accounts private key to query balances.

Answer (score 1):

Ethereum is not depended upon the unspent transaction output or UTXo. Instead, it depends on the state of the system. It only has account address linked with balance. For spending a certain amount, we only required an account with a balance greater than the amount to spend and its passphrase.[spending with wallet]

Comment: What adds your answer wrt to the other answer?